# How do I prove that basis transformation property?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, spaces

if space X can be described by basis b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,
then if i can find some subspace of X which can using linear

combination of basis b10,b20,b30,then can I found out b40,b50
and prove they(b40,b50) must exists?

It's a question came out of
looking https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IdtqGM6KWU&index=11&list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8,

(Lecture 11 of MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005)
the professor says dim(S+U)-dim(S and U) = dim(S) + dim(U),
I want to prove that as

transforming S to b1,b2,b3,b4,b5...
U to b1,b2,b3,(c4,c5)...
then S+U would be combining two basis and removing those common basis,
to prove that.

Comment: The question seems to be off-topic because it is about linear algebra (which is pure mathematics). Although not totally clear, the question seems to be about the following phenomenon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29#Extending_to_a_basis

Answer (score 0):

ok, I find my answer,
you can pick one arbitrary point from

X-{b10+b20+b30} (those point in X but not in the spaces of b10,b20,b30 forms) to use that as b40,
and then picking one arbitrary point

from X-{b10+b20+b30+b40} as b50,
according to basis theorem the length of

of basises of a space is same, so from that above process,
the new b would generate same length of basis as original ones,
neither more or less. that proved.